# sort and search mvc list view without call to server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple ASPNET MVC list view which passes a custom built model object.First time through I need to go out to the server and return a list of objects and display on the view.
I am building the view to allow sorting by different columns, searching and paging, and I have written all the code for this. However every time I am going to the server and pulling the data.

Can I cut down on these DB roundtrips by using the list that I obtained first time ?
If so how do I pass it from the view back to the controller?

Viewdata, Tempdata - or pass the `formcollection` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.knockoutjs.com this will give you a lot of functionality to manipulate the list in the browser and keeping the view in sync.

But it really depends on how big your list of objects is. If the quantity of data is large it is actually a more practical solution the way you implemented it already.

Comment: Hi thanks. I was hoping to stay away from javascript for the time being. Anyone got any other ideas on how it can be done in ASPNET MVC ?

Comment: I don't see how you can stay away from javascript if you plan to store and process the list in the browser. If you come up with a solution I would be curious to see it. Could you please post your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you go back to your controller you'll be going to server.

I supose you really mean that you don't want to requery again your database to obtain data filtered, sorted and paginated and would like just to sort or paginate data from your model view classes with data alreay on the view.

Keep in mind that this type of operation doesn't have to be always better than requerying your database, as you'll be sending more info through the net back to the server and, usually, programatically sorting of list-like elements are operations less optimized than sorted retrievals from database.

The critical decision here will be between the cost of your database query and the size of your listview element. If your query is light and gets (or can get) many results, sorting it will be more expensive than requerying, while if your query is complex and usually throws few results then, effectively, it will be more efficient to sort data without requerying database.

Try to create a new controller method for the sort, this method will receive as a parameter your list view model class, and you'll need, somehow, to send back to your server that info. I usually use AJAX calls where I pass data as JSON to the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment the data we're pulling back is small and lightweight - hence the idea to avoid recalling the database. As I said below, I was hoping to avoid JS and do it all in the Controller - but you're right if I am going back to server for Controller, I might aswell go the extra bit to the database too. Thanks again.